# Grails 3.0.11 mapping HTTP verbs

Tags: grails

I am building a RESTful controller by following the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restfulControllers):

```
import grails.transaction.*
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.*

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ProductController {
    def show(Product product) {
        respond product
    }
}
```

The docs state "Recall that each HTTP verb matches a particular Grails action according to the following conventions" but it seems this does not happen as `GET /product/1` or `DELETE /product/1` doesn't work, instead I must use `GET /product/show/1` and `GET /product/delete/1`

How do I enable the mapping of HTTP verbs to controller actions in Grails? thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use UrlMappings.groovy for define resources in grails, and declare actions in your controller show, index, save, update, create and others.

See the doc item 8.4.2 Mapping to REST resources.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings